# Как определить местоположение пользователя в yandex.mapkit

Tags: яндекс-карты, геолокация

Вот, собственно весь вопрос...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого необходима комбинация из LocationManager (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/mapkit/3.x/concepts/android/mapkit/ref/com/yandex/mapkit/location/LocationManager-docpage/ ) + LocationListener (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/mapkit/3.x/concepts/android/mapkit/ref/com/yandex/mapkit/location/LocationListener-docpage/ ). Нужно запросить один апдейт положения и, когда менеджер позовёт listener, посмотреть на getLastKnownLocation() . Например, для kotlin:

```
locationManager = MapKitFactory.getInstance().createLocationManager()
locationManager!!.requestSingleUpdate(object : LocationListener {
override fun onLocationStatusUpdated(p0: LocationStatus?) {
showMessage(p0?.toString() ?: "No status")
}
override fun onLocationUpdated(p0: Location?) {
showMessage(
"lat=${p0?.position?.latitude ?: ""} " +
"lon=${p0?.position?.longitude ?: ""}"
)
}
})
```

Comment: На Яве можно?))

Comment: @ЕвгенийПоловинкин, нет.)